# How to resolve this checkbox issue?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have added this condition

```
if (checkdaily.isChecked()){
    strcheckDialy="Y";
}else {
    strcheckDialy="N";
}
```

if checkbox is checked still N value is setting

I want Y when the checkbox is checked but always get N. How to solve this?

Comment: simply reverse the condition..lol...

Comment: @DhruvSakariya how would that help if they're *always* getting `"N"`?

Comment: Provide more code, cause it's impossible to tell ATM what the problem is. Try debugging your application and check what `isChecked` methods returns. Some things to check, whether `isChecked` really returns `true` , does `strcheckdialy` variable gets overrided further in logic, and is this code executed at all.

Comment: Are you listening to the onCheckedChanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use like this.

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            //checked
        } else {
            //not checked
        }
    }
});
```